# SwiftUI View Composition with VStack Text Not Working

Tags: swiftui, textfield, vstack

I am building a complex View with a number of different TextFields. I've shown a simplified version below- the first code block builds and runs. When I add an identical VStack block to it- the second code block, it fails to run- I get "the compiler is unable to type-check" error. Is the a child limit issue? I wish XCode provided decent error messaging!

Working.....

```
var body: some View {
    
    
    ScrollView() {
        
        
        VStack{   //  parts
            
            ForEach(Array(stride(from: 0, to: 461, by: 33)), id: \.self) { index_v in
                
                HStack {
                    VStack {
                        Group{
                            Text("resultsLine1")
                            Text(PartDisplay[index_v][0])
                            Text(db.sPart[index_v][1])
                            
                            if (db.sSelectedMode == "detailMode") {
                                Text("resultsLine4D")
                                Text("\(db.sPart[index_v][16]) \(db.sPart[index_v][19]) \(db.sPart[index_v][18])")
                                Text("results")
                                Text("\(db.sPart[index_v][22])")
                            } else {
                                Text("resultsLine4B")
                                Text("\(db.sPart[index_v][16])      \(db.sPart[index_v][18])")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.bottom, 6)
                    
                    VStack {
                        Group{
                            Text("resultsLine4")
                            Text(PartDisplay[index_v][2])
                            Text(db.sPart[index_v][3])
                            Text(db.sPart[index_v][4])
                            
                            if (db.sSelectedMode == "detailMode") {
                                Text("resultsLine4D")
                                Text("\(db.sPart[index_v][1]) \(db.sPart[index_v][3]) \(db.sPart[index_v][8])")
                                Text("results4")
                                Text("\(db.sPart[index_v][22])")
                            } else {
                                Text("resultsLine4B")
                                Text("\(db.sPart[index_v][16])      \(db.sPart[index_v][18])")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.bottom, 6)
                    

                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Not working..

```
var body: some View {
    
    
    ScrollView() {
        
        
        VStack{   //  parts
            
            ForEach(Array(stride(from: 0, to: 461, by: 33)), id: \.self) { index_v in
                
                HStack {
                    VStack {
                        Group{
                            Text("resultsLine1")
                            Text(PartDisplay[index_v][0])
                            Text(db.sPart[index_v][1])
                            
                            if (db.sSelectedMode == "detailMode") {
                                Text("resultsLine4D")
                                Text("\(db.sPart[index_v][16]) \(db.sPart[index_v][19]) \(db.sPart[index_v][18])")
                                Text("results")
                                Text("\(db.sPart[index_v][22])")
                            } else {
                                Text("resultsLine4B")
                                Text("\(db.sPart[index_v][16])      \(db.sPart[index_v][18])")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.bottom, 6)
                    
                    VStack {
                        Group{
                            Text("resultsLine4")
                            Text(PartDisplay[index_v][2])
                            Text(db.sPart[index_v][3])
                            Text(db.sPart[index_v][4])
                            
                            if (db.sSelectedMode == "detailMode") {
                                Text("resultsLine4D")
                                Text("\(db.sPart[index_v][1]) \(db.sPart[index_v][3]) \(db.sPart[index_v][8])")
                                Text("results4")
                                Text("\(db.sPart[index_v][22])")
                            } else {
                                Text("resultsLine4B")
                                Text("\(db.sPart[index_v][16])      \(db.sPart[index_v][18])")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.bottom, 6)
                    
                    VStack {
                        Group{
                            Text("resultsLine1")
                            Text(PartDisplay[index_v][0])
                            Text(db.sPart[index_v][1])
                            
                            if (db.sSelectedMode == "detailMode") {
                                Text("resultsLine14D")
                                Text("\(db.sPart[index_v][6]) \(db.sPart[index_v][9]) \(db.sPart[index_v][8])")
                                Text("results")
                                Text("\(db.sPart[index_v][2])")
                            } else {
                                Text("resultsLine4B")
                                Text("\(db.sPart[index_v][6])      \(db.sPart[index_v][18])")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.bottom, 6)
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Try to create subviews for each of the groups and maybe this will make it easier for the compiler. I am not sure if the code is just an example but it looks like all groups are exactly the same which in itself would be a very good reason to create a sub view instead of repeating the same code.

Comment: Thx. This is an example- in reality, the groups are indeed different.

Comment: Did you try to create sub views anyway?